# What the use of Thread constructor with string param?

Tags: java, multithreading

Looking at the Thread constructors, I see there is one that takes single string parameter. I have the below code, which is kind of useless. I would like to know, how to make a fruitful use of this constructor and make something actually run

```
public class ThreadTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t = new Thread("abc");
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Complete");
  }
}
```

Or Is it not supposed to be used the way I demonstrated above?

I perfectly know how to write multiple threads and execute :), I am just trying to understand the correct use of this constructor? Should it only be used by calling `super(name)` by extending Thread and not by the way I am using it above.

Comment: It provides the name of the thread. Check the javadoc.

Comment: I would like to know, how to make a fruitful use of it to actually write a code that executes in parallel.

Comment: The name of the thread has nothing to do with actually writing code that executes in parallel. Have you considered running through some of the zillion Java thread programming tutorials available everywhere?

Comment: That constructor is pretty pointless IMO.

Comment: I've found it to be useful when debugging. If a deadlock occurs, it's nice to know the origin of the thread.

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst That thread can't (cause) deadlock, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Then it's the thread itself that's pointless.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it is not that pointless. Sometimes helps you to track problems in specific threads created manually.

Comment: Did you RTM? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But a thread initialized with that constructor can't do anything. It will start and die. How can you possibly use it to debug?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I guess when you subclass `Thread`...but that's not recommended in most cases anyway. And `setName` has you covered.

Comment: @everyone I know how to write a thread and I have read the Manual. Please read my updated question to understand what I am asking.

Answer (score 3):

The thread class in itself doesn't do all that much. You have to extend it or construct it around a runnable to make it perform a task when run. From the doc:

start(): "Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread."

run(): "If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns."

Therefore constructing a new thread in your fashion and starting it does nothing. One use of the Thread(String) constructor is in subclasses:

```
public class Worker extends Thread{

    public Worker(int numb){
        super("worker-"+numb);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        //Stuff this thread actually does when run
        //....
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + i);
    }
}
```

To answer your second question in the comments, this is how you would write code that's executed in parallel. Consider the above class plus this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Worker w1 = new Worker(1);
    Worker w2 = new Worker(2);
    w1.start();
    w2.start();
}
```

The run methods of w1 and w2 will be executed in parallel. The order of the print statements will vary between executions of the main method.

Answer (score 2):

This particular constructor is used to specify the 'name' of a thread, which can later be used to distinguish between instances of a specific thread type.

[From the official Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.String));

> ### Thread
>
> ---
>
> *public Thread(String name)*
>
> Allocates a new Thread object. This
>   constructor has the same effect as Thread (null, null, name).
>
> **Parameters**: *name* - the name of the new thread

Once you have allocated a `Thread` a name, you can call the `getName()` method on the `Thread` instance to return the name it was given when it was created. This can be useful for debugging or for distinguishing between instances of of the same `Thread` subclass type.

Extra Reading:

- [Official Guide - Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply call this constructor you get a `Thread` which does nothing. Why? Look at the source code of `java.lang.Thread`. It has a `private Runnable target;` class variable. When you call this constructor, the `target` variable remains set to `null` (because this constructor simply sets the `Thread`'s name).

Also, the `run()` method of `java.lang.Thread` looks like this:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

So it means that this `run()` method will do nothing as `target` is `null`.

In order to create/start a `Thread` which really does something useful read here:

[The Java tutorial - how to run a thread?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)